# How to get attribute value from XML using VB.NET?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
    <Cube time='2016-09-12'>
        <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.1226'/>
        <Cube currency='JPY' rate='114.38'/>
    </Cube>
    </Cube>
    </gesmes:Envelope>
```

I want to get attribute value of each currency.
For now I am using this but it doesn't work:

```
    Dim xmlTree1 As New XmlDocument()
    xmlTree1.Load("C:\\download\eurofxref-daily.xml")

    Dim currencyUSD As String = xmlTree1.SelectSingleNode("/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube[@currency='USD']/@rate").Value
    Dim currencyJPY As String = xmlTree1.SelectSingleNode("/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube[@currency='JPY']/@rate").Value
```

Comment: Please post the xml you are attempting to extract from and the code where you create xmlTree1.

Comment: I have put the code of the XML and code where I create xmlTree1.

Comment: The `gesmes` prefix needs to be registered with the namespace. See this article on using the namespace manager https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318545

Comment: I resolved. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use the awesome Linq-to-XML features of VB.NET (Framework 3.5 and higher):

```
Imports <xmsns:xref="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">

...

Dim xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\kursna_standalone\download\eurofxref-daily.xml")
Dim cubes = xdoc.Root.<xref:Cube>.<xref:Cube>
Dim currencyUSD = cubes.Where(Function(x) x.currency = "USD").@rate
Dim currencyJPY = cubes.Where(Function(x) x.currency = "JPY").@rate
```

<sub>(Note: All my VB code examples assume that Option Strict and Option Infer are active).</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer Heinzi. This will work with NET.Framework 4 but currently I am using NET.Framework 2 and it doesn't recognize XDocument.

Comment: @SeaSide: .NET Framework 3.5 should work as well, if that is an option for you.

Comment: That's good to know, because I will certainly have to upgrade on the newer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following code to get the value from xml and it works:

```
 Dim xmlTree1 As New XmlDocument()
 xmlTree1.Load("C:\\kursna_standalone\download\eurofxref-daily.xml")

 Dim xmlnsManager1 As New System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xmlTree1.NameTable)
 xmlnsManager1.AddNamespace("gm1", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref")

 Dim currencyUSD As String = xmlTree1.SelectSingleNode("//gm1:Cube/gm1:Cube/gm1:Cube[@currency='USD']/@rate", xmlnsManager1).Value
 Dim currencyJPY As String = xmlTree1.SelectSingleNode("//gm1:Cube/gm1:Cube/gm1:Cube[@currency='JPY']/@rate", xmlnsManager1).Value
```